# comparing List A with List B and calculating total number of each item of List A in List B

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 lists; a and b. a contains usernames and each username is unique in this list. I read the usernames from the excel file with below.

```
a = pd.read_excel("user_name.xlsx", 'Sheet1')
```

[image: You may see user_name output below.]

The other list; b has also user names but the names are not unique, some names are listed more than once. 
[image: you may see list b sample as below.]

I want to count and print the number of user names in list b according to list a. For instance:  list a len is 700 and list b len is 300. I want to get a result as below. It means that username1 is listed in list b only once, username2 is not in list b, username699 is listed 5 times in list b, etc..

```
username1    1
username2    0
. 
.
. 
username699  5 
username700  2
```

I try below but it does not use list a as an index.  Can anyone advise how to solve this problem ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'username':list(b)})
da = df.groupby('username').count()
```

Comment: Why can't you just treat a and b as list and then do b.count(a[i]) for each element i in a?

Comment: for i in range(0, len(a):
        b.count(a[i])       I apply this but received this error. AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'levels'

Comment: That's because a should be a list not a pandas object. You can check the solution I have provided below for pandas.

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the comments, you could either do that or if you are steadfast on using pandas you can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'username':list(b)})
for i,row in enumerate(a.values):
    data = df[df['username'] == a.index[i]]
    print data.groupby(['username'])['username'].count()
```

Comment: It prints this.      Series([], dtype: float64)
Series([], dtype: float64)
Series([], dtype: float64)....